# Delay in HAL Library (HAL_Delay())

Tags: arm, keil, stm32f4discovery, hal

I'm trying to blink LEDs on my STM32F4 Discovery. Somehow it's stuck on the delay function. I have changed the SysTick interrupt priority to 0 and added the `IncTick()`, `GetTick()` functions. What am I missing?

```c
#include "stm32f4xx.h" // Device header
#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h" // Keil::Device:STM32Cube HAL:Common

int main() {
  HAL_Init();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_12 | GPIO_PIN_13 | GPIO_PIN_14 | GPIO_PIN_15;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_12 | GPIO_PIN_13 | GPIO_PIN_14 | GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_SET);
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_IncTick();
  HAL_GetTick();
  HAL_Delay(100);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_12 | GPIO_PIN_13 | GPIO_PIN_14 | GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Function `HAL_IncTick()` is called from `SysTick_Handler()` interrupt, which is usually implemented in `stm32f4xx_it.c`. You don't call this function from your code!

```
void SysTick_Handler(void)
{
    HAL_IncTick();
}
```

The function `HAL_Init()` initializes the SysTick timer to a 1ms interval and enables the associated interrupt. So, after calling `HAL_Init()` the function `HAL_Delay()` should be work properly.

**NOTE**: The STM32 HAL allows you to override (see keyword `__weak`) functions:

- `HAL_InitTick()`
- `HAL_IncTick()`
- `HAL_GetTick()`
- `HAL_Delay()`

So if you want to use the default delay mechanism you should not implement these functions in your code!